# Dynamodb context deadline exceeded through Spark Batch jobs

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-dax

My spark job accessing AWS dynamodb, under high load shows this error:

```
ERROR: Failed to refresh endpoint : RequestCanceled: request context canceled
caused by: context deadline exceeded
```

Any idea about this error?

Comment: Very likely due to throttling on the DynamoDB side, have you checked DDB metrics?

Comment: Thanks for your response @LeeHannigan.
Yes, I monitored the DDB metrics. But not having any severe throttling issues based on dynamic WCU/RCU min-max values.

We are handling the DynamoDB Throttling exception and doing the auto scaling options too.